# Where is GIS panel in Blender 2.82?

Tags: add-on

Hej, what happened with GIS panel in Blender 2.82 ? It was so useful and in good place up to 2.81 - why is it gone? Even in Manual for 2.81 there is no word on GIS features. Can someone help me find it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in feature for GIS in Blender. Most likely you installed one of these Add-ons :

Blender GIS :
https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS

or

Blender OSM :
https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm

Comment: I used it :) but I thought that from 2.8 it was there permanently because I didn't remember reinstalling plugin after changing to 2.81. I have reinstalled add-on and it works now. Thanks

Comment: There is an option to migrate all your add-ons when you install a new version, but it is only prompted once when you first launch the new version.